# Bind collection of objects to ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have class Person:

```
    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private String name = "";
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public Person()
        {
            NameProperty = "hi";
        }

        public Person(String _name)
        {
            NameProperty = _name;
        }

        public String NameProperty
        {
            get { return name; }
            set 
            { 
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("NameProperty");
            }
        }

        public override String ToString()
        {
            return NameProperty;
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {

            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }

        }

    }
```

And I can bind the instance of my class to TextBox:

```
myPerson = new Person("demas");
Binding myBinding = new Binding("NameProperty");
myBinding.Source = myPerson;
txtName.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Now I have collection of my class and want to bind it to ListBox:

```
List<Person> myCollection = new List<Person>(); // on the MainWindow level

myCollection.Add(new Person("one"));
myCollection.Add(new Person("two"));
myCollection.Add(new Person("three"));
```

So I have to see in the ListBox three values: one, two, three.  How can I do it?

Comment: I just don't know how to do it if my collection is created dynamically. Can you pls give code example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expose your collection as a public property in your `MainWindow`. If you want your `ListBox` to get updated when elements are added or removed to your collection, you should use an `ObservableCollection<T>` rather than `List<T>`.

```
readonly ObservableCollection<Person> myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Person>();

public ObservableCollection<Person> MyCollection
{
    get { return myCollection; }
}
```

Then, in your XAML, use data binding to reference the property:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        xmlns:p="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Properties"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameProperty}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Don’t forget to set the `DataContext` either on your `ListBox` or on its parent window.

P.S. Identifier names should identify the purpose, not the type. Use `Persons` instead of `MyCollection`; use `Name` instead of `NameProperty`.

Comment: Thans. It helps me. Excelent answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use ObservableCollection instead of List. That will update the UI when you add/remove items to/from the collection. Once you have the collection, bind it to ItemsSource property of the ListBox.

Additionally you can control how Person objects are rendered on the UI by either overriding the ToString method on Person class or setting an ItemTemplate on ListBox control.

Comment: But for a simple dropdown you usually don't need mutations.

Comment: I was trying to use ItemSource, but new elements of collection didn't display on ListBox, while I didn't reexecute listNames.ItemsSource = null; listNames.ItemsSource = myCollection;

Comment: You don't have to replace ItemSource if you use an ObservableCollection.